# Define functions over 2 parallel modules built by functors

Tags: types, module, ocaml, functor

I am still struggling with my design and implementation, thought it progresses...

First, I have defined 2 basic signatures and 2 modules:

```
module type MATRIX = sig type 'a t end    
module MatrixArray: MATRIX = struct
  type 'a t = 'a array array
end

module type MMM = sig type 'a t end
module MmmArray: MMM = struct
  type 'a t = 'a array array
end
```

Then I have defined 3 signatures, 3 functors and applied them with the basic modules above:

```
module type AMATRIX = sig
  include MATRIX
  module Mmm : MMM
  module Matrix: MATRIX
  val g: 'a Mmm.t -> 'a Matrix.t -> 'a Mmm.t * 'a Matrix.t
end
module AMatrixFun (Mmm: MMM) (Matrix: MATRIX) : AMATRIX with module Mmm = Mmm and module Matrix = Matrix = struct
  include MatrixArray
  module Mmm = Mmm
  module Matrix = Matrix
  let g (mmm: 'a Mmm.t) (dbm: 'a Matrix.t) : 'a Mmm.t * 'a Matrix.t = failwith "to do"
end
module AMatrixArray  = AMatrixFun(MmmArray)(MatrixArray)

module type VIDBM = sig
  module Matrix: MATRIX
  type t = | Dtop | Dbot | D of int Matrix.t
end
module ViDbmFun (Matrix: MATRIX) : VIDBM with module Matrix = Matrix = struct
  module Matrix = Matrix
  type t = | Dtop | Dbot | D of int Matrix.t
end
module ViDbmArray = ViDbmFun(MatrixArray)

module type AREAMMM = sig
  module Mmm: MMM
  type t = | Mtop | Mbot | M of int Mmm.t
end
module AreaMmmFun (Mmm: MMM) : AREAMMM with module Mmm = Mmm = struct
  module Mmm = Mmm
  type t = | Mtop | Mbot | M of int Mmm.t
  let f (am: t) (vd: ViDbmArray.t) : t * ViDbmArray.t =
    let (M mmm), (ViDbmArray.D dbm) = am, vd in
    (AMatrixArray.g mmm dbm);
    failwith "to do"
end
module AreaMmmArray  = AreaMmmFun(MmmArray)
```

Actually I need to define a function `f: AreaMmmArray.t -> ViDbmArray.t -> AreaMmmArray.t * ViDbmArray.t` which requires another function `g: 'a Mmm.t -> 'a Matrix.t -> 'a Mmm.t * 'a Matrix.t`. As it involves the types of several parallel modules, my major question is in which modules I should define them.

In the code above, as a try, I have implemented `f` in `ViDbmFun` and `g` in `AMatrixFun`. The compilation stops at `(AMatrixArray.g mmm dbm);` and gives me:

```
Error: This expression has type int Mmm.t = int Mmm.t
       but an expression was expected of type
         'a AMatrixArray.Mmm.t = 'a MmmArray.t
```

I think the error is reasonable, because `int Mmm.t` in `AreaMmmFun` may be something other than `MmmArray.t` forced in `AMatrixArray`... Is there a way to work around this?

Again, I think the major question is where to define `f` and `g`, could anyone help?

Comment: You're missing module `Mmt` in your sample.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `Mmm`, I have fixed it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you are not at the right level of definition indeed. `Matrix` and `Mmm` are independent, and put together to make an `AMatrix. Here you try to define a function that speaks about both`Matrix`and`Mmm`in a`FooMmmFun`functor, which only knows about`Mmm`, not`Matrix`; using the particular instance`MatrixArray` is not the solution, and you get a type error trying to do that.

You have to define `f` at a level that knows about both `Matrix` (or `ViDbm`) and `Mmm` (or `AreaMmm`). Here is my suggestion, to add to your code after the declaration of the `AREAMMM` signature. It mostly define a functorized layer for `AMatrix`, as you did for `Matrix` and `MMM`.

```
(* does not speak about `f` as no `Matrix` is available *)
module AreaMmmFun (Mmm: MMM) : AREAMMM with module Mmm = Mmm = struct
  module Mmm = Mmm
  type t = | Mtop | Mbot | M of int Mmm.t
end
module AreaMmmArray  = AreaMmmFun(MmmArray)

(* a functor over `AMatrix`, that knows both `Matrix` and `Mmm`,
   so we can define `f` here. I don't know which signature you want. *)
module AMatrixFun (AMatrix : AMATRIX)
= struct
  module ViDbm = ViDbmFun(AMatrix.Matrix)
  module AreaMmm = AreaMmmFun(AMatrix.Mmm)

  let f (am: AreaMmm.t) (vd: ViDbm.t) : AreaMmm.t * ViDbm.t =
    let (AreaMmm.M mmm), (ViDbm.D dbm) = am, vd in
    (AMatrix.g mmm dbm);
    failwith "to do"
end

module AmatrixFooArray = AMatrixFun(AMatrixArray)
```

PS: you could define a parametric type for types closed by top/bottom, to avoid duplication of constructor names. Outside of any module:

```
type 'a order = Top | Bot | D of 'a
```

Then you can define `VIDBM.t` as `int Matrix.t order`, and `AREAMMM.t` as `int Mmm.t order`, instead of having two incompatible types and families of constructors (`Mtop`, `Dtop`...).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but as you say, referring to the specific `AMatrix` instance in the `AreaMmm` functor does not make sense. There are only two solutions: you either need to parameterize the `AreaMmm` functor over an instance of `AMATRIX with module Mmm = Mmm`, or you have to construct a suitable instance inside the functor.